# How to install Android Studio in specified directory

Tags: software-installation, android-studio

I have very little free space on my partition for the OS but I want to install Android Studio on my Ubuntu (18.04.02 LTS).

I saw that `sudo snap install android-studio --classic` should install it but I want to find a way to do it on a specified directory on another disk or partition.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should install Android Studio using the zipped version.

1. Download this [file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles)
2. Move it to the drive/partition destination. Suppose your partition with free space is /home

> ```
> sudo mv ~/Downloads/android-studio-ide-182.5314842-linux.zip /home
> ```

3. Extract the file:

> ```
> unzip /home/android-studio-ide-182.5314842-linux.zip
> ```

4. In order to have this available from other locations create a launcher for the Android Studio, look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

I hope this helps!

Comment: The answer contains a link in the first line, 'Download this file', but it is only a link to a Ubuntu help page which has no element of Android on it. The sought-for file is likely to be found on this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @PhilippeDelteil 's answer

1. Download the [latest Android studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/).
2. Move the `zip/tar.gz` file to the desired disk/directory/partition (remember to mount the partition first).
3. Extract the contents of the `zip/tar.gz` file.
4. Then `cd android-studio/bin/`.
5. Run `./studio.sh`, this will launch the setup wizard.
6. Fill the appropriate areas and click next.
7. When you reach `Install type` select `custom` instead of `standard` then click next.
8. In the `SDK components setup` change the default installation location to your desired disk/directory/partition.

This will install Android studio and its sdk in a custom location. To run android studio, go to `FULLPATH/android-studio/bin/` and again run `./studio.sh`.